# readonly properties and ngOnInit

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, readonly-attribute

Readonly properties can only be assigned in the constructor, but in angular it is discouraged and sometimes impossible to use the constructor for certain initialization and instead the angular hook ngOnInit is used.
Is there any way to mark ngOnInit as a constructor with regard to the readonly attribute so that I can use readonly for essentially immutable properties that are only assigned a single time in ngOnInit?

edit: To clarify: im not looking for alternative ways to declare readonly properties. I want to declare them the regular way. Anything else I think would not be worth the tradeoff in readability just to get that static check.
I was hoping there would be some annotation like there are for tslint to ignore the immutability inside ngOnInit.

From the answers so far I guess assigning them as `(this as any).foo = bar;` is the closest to what I would like to do, though I guess it's still uglier than just leaving out the readonly.

Comment: You can initialize property values inside constructor. There's no problem in it.

Comment: _but in angular it is discouraged_ where did you got this from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't mark a method as a constructor there is just no syntax for that. You can break the `readonly` which is just a compile time check by using a type assertion to `any` and access any public/private property you want in a type unsafe way. You can also use a mapped type to make the type mutable, but it only works for public properties:

```
type Mutable<T> = { -readonly [ P in keyof T]: T[P] }

class Foo {
    public readonly data: string;
    private readonly pdata: string;
    public init() {
        const ref: Mutable<this> = this;
        ref.data = "" 
        const pRef = this as any;
        pRef.pdata = ""

        const pSaferRef: { pdata: string } = this as any;
        pSaferRef.pdata = ""
    }
}
```

Comment: But does it make the readonly non-readonly again, should we revert the readonly state?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Readonly is just something the compiler checks. `ref`, `pRef` and `pSaferRef` are just references to `this` that are not typed as readonly and thus we can do whatever we want .. `this.data` is still readonly if you try to access it

Answer (score 5):

> Readonly properties can only be assigned in the constructor

Not true

```
class MyClass {
  readonly prop1 = 'prop1';
  constructor(
    public readonly prop2 = 'prop2'
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'prop3', { wirtable: false, value: 'prop3'});
  }
}
```

As you see, there is already 3 ways of defining them. And probably more !

> but in angular it is discouraged and sometimes impossible to use the constructor for certain initialization and instead the angular hook ngOnInit is used

It is "discouraged" for newcomers, because it's easier to tell them not to do that, rather than explaining in depth the lifecycle of the framework. The point is, you can use the constructor as you please, especially for stuff unrelated to Angular (like read-only variables).

> Is there any way to mark ngOnInit as a constructor

A constrcutor is a constructor. You can't define a method to be a constructor. You can only call a method in the constructor, but that won't solve your issue.

> so that I can use readonly for essentially immutable properties that are only assigned a single time in ngOnInit?

Answer and bottom line : **use your constructor as you please**. Put your readonly properties in it if you want.

Also, consider providing some sandbox or at least some code, so that we can make an answer that is adapted to both your code and your need.

Comment: Wow, learned something new today. Thanks! Will modify my answer. However, how future proof is this? Could changes to typescript not break this?

Comment: Did a little research myself. Apparently, it is as future proof as anything in the javascript ecosystem - that is, the writable property is defined by javascript, not something added on by typescript

Comment: technically, the first 2 "alternatives" that you present are variations of constructor initialization, as they are transpiled into such.

Comment: @nosnahoj-trap meaning ?

Comment: I was referring to the usage of Object.defineProperty

Comment: @Jota.Toledo I don't dispute that, but if you want to go that far, [they're actually not readonly](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20X%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20prop1%20%3D%20'prop1'%3B%0D%0A%7D), so let's focus on typescript !

Comment: @nosnahoj-trap Yes, this is a javascript feature, not a typescript one, but I don't see what you want to say, so I was aking more explanation ! (not a native speaker, I might miss something in your sentence)

Comment: @nosnahoj-trap Oh I didn't see you edited your first comment. Now your comments makes more sense ahah. So to answer you (even though you already found the answer), yes, it is future-proof !

Comment: I am looking for alternative ways to initialize them, not declare them, while preferably declaring them in the first way from your snippet. I assume with defineproperty I lose the static check which is the main point. Ill edit my question to make it clearer.

Comment: @Simon Javascript doesn't have read-only properties. You can declare a read-only variable and use the define property method to assign a new variable to it. You can also type the variable as any to change its value like a casual variable. But there's only one way to instanciate it correctly, and it's the first one. If you want to change the value of a read-only property, then it's not a read-only property. Consider finding another coding design, instead of trying to go around.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use a setter and a getter in place of `readonly`?

```
export class MyComponent {
  private _value: string;
  set value(v: string) {
    if (!this._value) {
      this._value = v;
    } else {
      throw new TypeError('Assignment to read-only variable');
    }
  }

  get value() {
    return this._value;
  }
}
```

Comment: @trichetriche it's not a workaround, because it's the real use of getters and setters, it's very used, also in the implementation of some native functions. `readonly` is used to initialize a variable as you declare it, so any other use that's not this, is an actual workaround.

Comment: Getters and setters aren't readonly properties. They are variable accessors. So yes, this is a workaround. Not only that, but you don't actually write "readonly" in your code. That shows it is a workaround. You also implement a custom error, while TS already has an error for readonly properties. All of those reasons confirm it is a workaround. And in JS, you have ways of declaring variables as readonly. Again, I'm not saying what you say is false, I'm just saying this is not a solution but a workaround, and not a clean one. But it sure can be used !

Answer (score 0):

That is a good question. <strike>You could get something similar going on via a setter:</strike>

```
...
    protected _pseudoReadonlyProp: number = -1 // or some other value, that marks unititialized state
    set pseudoReadonlyProp(a: number) {
        if(this._pseudoReadonlyProp != -1) {
           // throw some error here
        }
        this._pseudoReadonlyProp = a
    }
    get pseudoReadonlyProp(): number {
        return this._pseudoReadonlyProp
    }
...
```

Yet another way to get similar behavior would be to encapsulate the read only member in a class, put it in your component and create a new instance of the class in ngInit or some other component initialization function.

Considering Object.defineProperty exists, a better way would be to use it as pointed out by @trichetriche